# PHP5 + Code Ignite 3.1 + Xdebug 2.2.5.1 Segmentation fault

Tags: php, segmentation-fault, xdebug

I've been trying use **php5-xdebug** to remote debug a legacy PHP 5 with Code Ignite 3.1 application. Debugging is causing segmentation fault in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` when Xdebug is enabled. With Xdebug disabled, everything works fine (but no way to debug).

For while, I'm going to disable Xdebug and write some `log_message()` to investigate code problems.

Here, the Apache2 error log message:

> [core:notice] [pid 17627] AH00051: child pid 17634 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /tmp

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You better upgrade. Xdebug v2 is not supported since v3 has been released (like 2 years now I think). If it's not possible -- check here for the old versions (if you are OK compiling Xdebug from the source and can find a version that works): https://xdebug.org/download/historical

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5 has been discontinued since Dec 31st, 2018. Please upgrade: https://www.php.net/eol.php

There is also no supported version of Xdebug for PHP 5 either: https://xdebug.org/docs/compat